# Warnings on code run that I want to delete

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, warnings

I'm using code that shows me a lot of useless warnings like `change np.arrow for tf.arrow` or `this version will be fixed in next versions`... That warning doesn't help me cause I really don't need it now and want to know how to supress or delete it.

I tried warning_ignore... and another codes with warningfilter but none of these work and the warnings still being visible.

```
Using TensorFlow backend. WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr. W0709 10:34:02.424996 12116 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

W0709 10:34:02.484447 12116 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

W0709 10:34:02.499438 12116 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3976: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

W0709 10:34:02.514367 12116 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\ROBERTO VILCHEZ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:245: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.
```

Thats just some of a lot of warnings with the same form, I just want to delete it. I try to replace tf.... with tf... but my code doesnt work, for that reason I just want to delete those warnings.

Answer (score 0):

try to set log level

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```